# A manga about people fighting past historical figures such as Jack the Ripper

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember reading a manga around 2010-2012 where characters have to fight historical figures that they are the reincarnation of and the first chapter features a fight against Jack the Ripper. Jack the Ripper is represented as a monster guy with a lot of blades coming out everywhere.

It must have been a short serialization and dropped after a few chapters as I never heard of it again. The story was serialized so it is not a one-shot.

I also remember something about the main character losing against him and then a girl appearing to save him both are reincarnations of someone.

Comment: I also remember something about the main character losing against him and then a girl appearing to save him both are reincarnations of someone.

Comment: Although it's not the answer, the idea of fighting past historical figures reminds me of the game "Waxworks", in which you travel into various time period to take the place of your ancestors to take down the "bad guys".

Comment: The only one I can think of is Soul Eater, though it doesn't fit any of the reincarnation aspects.

Comment: So far I've found that Zodiac Game is the most similar I've seen yet but it is not exactly that. It just follows the same tropes generally in the first chapter.

Comment: Just looked through all the titles listed in Baka updates from around the time that fit the genre, no dice so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean "Reincarnation no Kaben"?

https://myanimelist.net/manga/75487/Reincarnation_no_Kaben

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you [edit] this answer to explain why you think this might be the correct manga though, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question?

Comment: Yes this was it!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Might this be *[Nobunagun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobunagun)*...?

It has a similar sounding plot, and the first chapter was released in 2011, so it's old enough to be the one you read. Also, there were only six volumes released in total.

> **To protect the world from the impending invasion of the alien species known only as "Evolutionary Invasion Objects" (EIO), the supranational organization DOGOO created special warriors through DNA manipulation called E-Gene holders. These E-Gene holders are the reincarnations of various historical figures.** Using special weapons called AU balls, E-gene holders can call forth AU weapons with an affinity to their assigned historical figure and use it against the invaders. Sio Ogura is one of them, being the reincarnation of Oda Nobunaga. However, her memories of her past life are limited only by dreams about the military past. Going on a school trip in Taiwan, Sio gets caught in the middle of a battle between Evolutionary Invasion Objects and Dogoo's E-gene holders, alongside her classmate Kaoru Asao. **When one of the E-Gene holders, the reincarnation of Jack the Ripper, gets incapacitated and Kaoru ends up in danger when confronting an Evolutionary Invasion Object, Sio uses Jack's AU ball to fully activate her E-Gene holder status. She gains her AU weapon, a massive machine gun, and assists the other E-Gene holders to put an end to the Taiwan invasion.** After some reluctance, she joins DOGOO at Kaoru's behest.

Comment: Although it does share a lot of similarities this is most definitely not the one I am looking for. I've also looked at Nobunagun in case it was what I was thinking it was but it's completely different. Jack the ripper here is a guy and fairly good looking while in the one I remember he was some sort of weird monster full of claws.